# Android in-app billing permission, now or later?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am developing an Android app, the first version will be totally free but I am planning to add in-app purchases in app version 3 or 4. What's the best practice, add in-app billing permission from version 1, or add it when needed (forcing users to approve the new permission on version update) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it when it is needed would be best practice from a consumer standpoint. Seeing an app requests permissions that i dont understand why is needed would make me less likely to use the app.